# Good way to build a secure quiz in PHP and Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am building a PHP/jQuery/AJAX timed quiz.
As you might've figured from the AJAX, i want the quiz completely so that the user does not have to refresh the page, or submit any forms.

So, lets take a maths quiz for example.
What i want is, every time a user answers a question, i want it to say whether the answer was right or wrong however the thing i cant workout how to do is, securely receive the answers from the server so the user cant read them (for example not in plain text)

I have thought of a way to get the questions in a way which a script or something cant be used for cheating. To do this, I will make the page request the questions from the server and a bunch of image URLs (created using PHP) will be returned so that's all fine and worked out.

However my problem is how the client page will know the answers without the user figuring it out? I have thought about sending an AJAX request to the server every time a question is answered and checking if it is right or wrong however that will take wayyy too much time to complete the quiz.

Another way (which is the best so far) is to send an AJAX request to get the answers, and the items that are returned from that are a bunch of random letters and numbers along with like a "deciphering" code which the jQuery script can use to work out the answers and check if they are right after every question (so basically obfuscate the answers, however using this way, a user can read my jQuery code and use it to find out how it works out the answers and then decipher the answers to cheat)

Another way is by submitting all the users zanswers at the end of the quiz via AJAX, then the server checks and returns how many are right/wrong then telling the user which ones they got right or wrong however I'd like to avoid this as i want a way so they know after each question if they got the last one right or not.

So what i am basically asking is, is there any secure way (in which the user can't possible work out the answers) to get the answers from the server using AJAX before every quiz and using jQuery to tell the user after every question if they got it right or wrong?

Comment: If the answers are in the browser available for your code to see, anyone using the browser can see them too.  You have to check the answers on the server.  There is no other secure way.

Comment: "However, that will take way to much time" -> no, why? A typical request should take < 100ms, how will that be in the way of the user experience?

Comment: Thanks for your replies

to Paul Jan - However some people may have a slower connection and since its a timed quiz, lets say for some reason someones connections slows down, whether for a couple of seconds or just generally slow, then sending an ajax request after every question would waste valuable time to complete the quiz

Comment: What would be your way of doing it? Would you obfuscate the code so people would perhaps be put off cheating or would you just send the answers after the quiz, where although the user can't see if they got a question right or wrong after they answered it, it is still secure so no one can cheat (There will be a high scores table for every quiz which is why i dont really want anyway to cheat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practise for doing such types of quiz is to reveal the answer after the user has answered all the questions.Since the user may want to modify his/her answer...so i suggest you to get the questions via ajax and display the final score by checking the answers given by the user with the answers in the database by ajax!

Comment: Hey Shrikanth, thanks for your answer! I guess this would be the best way to do it, Thanks

Comment: Glad i could be of help.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.
Once you send the answers to the client in a format you can use to determine if the user entered the correct answer, the user is also able to decrypt the answers before answering a question.

The only way this can be done securely is by not having the answers at the client site. Thus, you need to obtain the correctness of the answer from the server. I suggest looking at ways to speed u the verification process on the server. For instance by storing the answers in the session.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, i think the best way to do it would be to send the answers at the end for verification as i want as little delay between questions since it will be a timed quiz